# What data structure has these properties?

Tags: data-structures

I need a structure for storing data such that all of the following operations are logarithmic time:

The structure represents an ordered list of unique elements.  The following operations need to be supported:

1. Add an element to the right end of the list.
2. Remove an element, from anywhere in the list.
3. Get the length of the list.
4. Get the element at a given index into the list.
5. Get the index of a given element.

As an example, if this structure is implemented as a simple python list, operations 1 , 3, and 4 are (amortized) constant time, with the 2 and 5 being linear (5 can be made logarithmic relatively easily, but 2 remains problematic).

The only way I've thought of to do this would be to have a hash table storing the number of insertions done before each element, along with a binary search tree (which would have to be self balancing) that stores pairs `(i, value)`, where the `i` is how many insertions were done before the value, and is the order used to make it a BST, where in addition each node also stores the total size of the subtree rooted at it (which would need to be propagated upwards whenever any node was changed).  This seems like an overly complicated scheme, is there a simpler structure that can achieve logarithmic or better performance in all of the listed operations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is called an [Order statistic tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic_tree), usually implemented as a self-balancing binary search tree (e.g. Red-black tree) with one extra field stored at each node: the size of the subtree rooted at that node.

All normal BST operations have to be modified slightly to maintain correct sizes, but the last 3 operations (get the length, get the element at an index, get the index of an element) can all be implemented fairly simply. The first is just the size field of the root node; the other two operations are easier if you know that 'x is the kth largest element if and only if the number of elements smaller than x is k-1', and that the left (respectively, right) subtrees of a node contain only smaller (respectively, larger) elements than the current node.

It also helps to think about how searches in a BST are structured: starting at the root, to search for 'x' in a BST, we move left if 'x' is smaller than the current node value, and move right if *the current node and its entire left subtree* is smaller than 'x', so the index of an element is exactly the sum of the number of those smaller values.